# Displaying progress indicator while in-app purchase (or restored purchase) on iPhone is being processed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

How do I show a progress indicator during processing of in-app purchase on iPhone? I know how to display progress/activity indicator itself, but I need to know when to start it. If I start it right after calling

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

method I will see the indicator when user is presented with iTunes account password prompt. I would like to start the progress when this prompt has been already passed. Also, the same thing for restoring completed transactions:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

I tried to hook up the indicator to SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing state within

```
paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

but still get it started before the password prompt. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that there is a progress notification for the transaction.  What I do for IAP is to throw up a spinner.  The only time you can really display progress is if the purchase includes a download, from which you can track download progress on your own.

Comment: Can you tell me when do you start showing a spinner? After the password prompt? How do you know when user passed this prompt?

Comment: For restoring, I have a button to restore purchases.  I show the spinner when that button is pressed and I receive a delegate callback from the queue when it fails, cancels, or is successful.  You should got check out the Apple documentation for how this all works: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html  Ray Wenderlich has a great tutorial, also, that covers all of it in a very good way: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases

Comment: Wayne, so in your case the spinner is starts before even the password dialog is shown? If course it's a possibility, if you center it on screen, so password hides it and it's not visible until password prompt goes away. Is this correct?

Comment: @Antonio, I actually place the spinner in the button that initiated the call.  But you can add a spinner anywhere you want.  I actually don't mind that the spinner is there for the password dialogue because it is an indicator to the user that work is being done.  I think it would be more egregious to have the spinner appearing/disappearing throughout the process.  Keep it there until all the work is done.